# Coverage testing with pytest-cov and subprocess.Popen

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, subprocess, pytest-cov

How to test an application with multiple processes, collecting coverage of them all, using Popen?

The pytest-cov documentation only covers the multiprocessing module, not subprocess.
https://pytest-cov.readthedocs.io/en/latest/subprocess-support.html

My application uses Popen to start new copies of itself. All children are SIGTERMed (which is handled so that they exit normally) and then waited for by their parents. However, the coverage reports show some lines of execution in the first child until it calls Popen (shown in red), and some lines in grandchildren. I suspect that coverage report files may get overwritten by the multiple processes. No simple test case, sorry.

Comment: You will have to set up `coverage` to activate in subprocesses, see [here](https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/latest/subprocess.html). This requires 1. modification of your Python installation (which is fairly easy if you're using virtual environments) and 2. modification of your code - however, you didn't provide any. You will have to pass the `COVERAGE_PROCESS_START` env var to the spawned subprocesses.

Comment: This might be platform-dependent. Linux CI pipeline gets coverage but Windows and OSX don't, even though all platforms execute the same code. Also, it could be just that on many test runs and with random outcome on which process gets covered, in combined test results it is likely that both are.

Comment: @hoefling I believe that the pytest-cov plugin is already supposed to handle that but I'll see if doing it manually would help, and also if I could produce a small test case showing this problem.